# PowerShell Drag & Drop Fails

Tags: powershell, drag-and-drop

Having issues with Drag & Drop of a file in the ps1 script below. It does not work ("Event Drop" does not output) with PowerGui, PowerShell ISE, nor as

```
$installDir = Split-Path -Path $myinvocation.mycommand.path
& $env:SystemRoot\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -sta (Join-Path $installDir "TestDrop.ps1")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
## TestDrop.ps1 for testing drag & drop

function DragNDrop {
#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::Load("System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::Load("mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::Load("System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089") | Out-Null

#endregion

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 

$handler_DragEnter={    
    write-host "$Event Enter" 
    $Event.Effect = "Copy" # not sure about this ...
}

$objForm.Text = "Test Drag & Drop"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.SizeGripStyle = 'Hide'
$objForm.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'

$objTextBox.AllowDrop = $true
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,25) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,120)  
$objTextBox.Multiline = $true
$objTextBox.TabIndex = 1
$objTextBox.Text = "Try to Drag & Drop File Here..."
$objTextBox.Add_DragEnter({ write-host "Event Enter" })
$objTextBox.Add_DragDrop({ write-host "Event Drop" })
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox)
$objForm.Topmost = $True

return $objForm.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

DragNDrop | Out-Null
```

Comment: " It does not work" - In what fashion?

Comment: The write-host command does not execute/output

Comment: Is this the entire body of the script?  It looks like a lot is missing.

Comment: Specifically, there are variables that you reference but aren't set to anything, like `$Handler_DragEnter` and `$Event`

Comment: This is The Full Monty - last line is DragNDrop | Out-Null

Comment: @Les - then how are you defining `$event` and `$handler_dragenter`?  I tried to run this and it wouldn't even execute because of the variables you call with no assignment.  Did you inherit this from someone else?

Comment: $Event is powershell variable so I changed lines: $objTextBox.Add_DragEnter({ write-host "Event Enter" }) 
$objTextBox.Add_DragDrop({ write-host "Event Drop" }). Now "Event Enter" is output, but "Event Drop" is not.

Comment: @Les - then where does the `$handler_dragenter` come from?

Comment: Sorry, missed = at end of $handler_dragenter=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should enable droppiong like this

```
$objTextBox.Add_DragEnter({ 
  write-host "Event Enter" 
  $_.Effect = 'Copy'
})
```

Comment: Got it /spasibo!/    if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop, $false)) 
   {
      $_.Effect = "Copy"
   }